# redirect http to https with custom port

Tags: apache, https

I have an apache virtual host using port 8080 and I'm wanting to use https for it.  Normally you would detect *:80 and redirect to https, but in this case it's a custom port and therefore I can't assume http or https.

If you attempt to access the site via http you get a BAD REQUEST response due to the wrong scheme.

What I would like to do is instead redirect back to https.  Unfortunately, it doesn't seem like I'm able to do that.  I've attempted to use the rewrite engine, but it looks as though apache responds with the BAD REQUEST before the rewrite engine is even activated (this is my guess).

Is there a good way to enable this?  I can't simply use port 80 and redirect because there will be multiple virtual hosts on this server that are differentiated by the port.

Comment: Check this answer (and comments) https://serverfault.com/questions/803776/serving-port-443-over-http-creates-400-bad-request-error-instead-of-redirect

Comment: thank you, that answers my question.